# Loci Of a Circle In The Complex Plane

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve:
$$\text{|z - 1| = 3|z + 2|, where z = x+iy}$$
workbook is asking for a sketch, but unfortunately it does not provide any answers.

I seem to struggle to draw this so I am solving these types of problems algebraically and plotting afterwards.

As there are no answers in the book I wanted to know if I have found the answer 
$$\text{|z + $\frac{19}{4}$| = $\frac{\sqrt{291}}{4}$}$$

many Thanks in advance

Comment: Is $z$ a complex number, right?

Comment: yes z is a complex number

Comment: Draw a real line on the paper, and an imaginary line in your mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is the same as
$$|z - 1|^2 = 9|z + 2|^2$$
Use the fact that $|a + ib|^2 = a^2 + b^2$ to convert the above into an equation in $x$ and $y$, where $z = x + iy$. You should be able to identify the result as a specific conic section (parabola, hyperbola, ellipse etc).

Comment: Thanks, for your help trying to learn this from a textbook with 2 examples!

Comment: Working through the solution I am sure that the answer stated above is the correct answer

Comment: It might be, I didn't work it out.. but the method I described should give the correct answer.